# How to run a one-off command at a specified future time in Guix?

Tags: linux, command-line, at, guix

I want to run a shell command once at a specific time in the future on Guix. My idea was to use the `at` command, but that seems to not be available on Guix.

The imperative nature of my desire goes against the declarative philosophy of Guix somewhat, which I expect is the (indirect) reason `at` is not available.

For example, `at` requires `atrun` or `atd` to be running, which might not fit nicely in the Guix way of doing things.

Is there perhaps a Guix-specific way of running a command at a specific time that I have not found yet?

For the moment I can just do a `sleep xxx; cmd`, which should be good enough for now.

---

This is my solution based on @GAD3R suggestion to use `mcron`, and the [manual on how to emulate `at`](https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/mcron.html#AT-commands)

`~/.config/hello.guile`:

```
(job '(next-minute-from (current-time) '(25))
     (lambda () (system "echo $(date) >> ~/hello.txt")
                (kill (getppid) SIGINT)))
```

and then call `mcron`.

This indeed added a line to `~/hello.txt` at 25 minutes past the hour.

It is a bit more work than using `at`, but it does work.

Two potential improvements I can see:

- It seems that `job` simply expects a function that returns a unix timestamp as first argument. So I suppose it would be feasible to give it the exact timestamp that is necessary. That might also make the killing part redundant.
- I suppose that instead of calling `mcron` manually, it is maybe better to use the [mcron Home Service](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/devel/en/html_node/Mcron-Home-Service.html)

Finally, maybe it would be worthwhile to explicitly state that `mcron` replaces also `atd` or `atrun`, as those where terms I knew and searched for. For some reason I did not think that cron should also be able to approximate what I looked for. Maybe I'll write a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `mcron` via a posix or guile (scheme) script then run `mcron &`. Or install `cron`, `crond` or `crontab` as root.

scripts goes under  `~/.config/cron`.

Posix scripts should have the `.vixie` or `.vix` extensions.

Guile scripts should have `.guile` or `.gle` extensions.

[The GNU documentation: mcron](https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/mcron.html)

Comment: Oh... I didn't run `mcron` itself. My self-assessment in the first sentence of my previous comment seems about right.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I didn't think about trying to use `mcron`, and if I did, I might have only checked the Gux manual and would therefor perhaps not see the at-substitution instructions. (Deleted my first comment where I was not paying attention.)